# PHP xml parsing, not sure what the term is for this

Tags: php, xml

`<guid isPermaLink="true">/125843</guid>`

How would I get "true" out of that? I honestly can't think of name for it right now.. can't be namespace..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

guessing your using SimpleXML, since you didnt name the Parser.

Answer (score 0):

That is an attribute of the XML element. You can use [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse XML in PHP. (It has a fairly simple API)

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to get the attribute

```
$xmlstr = '<guid isPermaLink="true">/125843</guid>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$ispermalink = $xml->xpath('/guid[@isPermaLink]');
foreach ($ispermalink[0]->attributes() as $k => $v) {
    print "isPermaLink... $v \n";
}
```